# Regex append a string to a part of the match

Tags: regex, geany

I find this quite hard to do, the thing is as follows:

I have a string in the form:

```
GlobalParameters::$docId = DocList::$PARTNERS;
```

And I want to append the string *_VIEW* to the end of the symbol. The problem is that I want not only to match *PARTNERS* but any other symbol too, so I tried this regex:

Find:

```
GlobalParameters\:\:\$docId\ \=\ DocList\:\:\$(.*)\;
```

Replace with:

```
GlobalParameters\:\:\$docId\ \=\ DocList\:\:\$(.*)_VIEW\;
```

But I just got:

```
GlobalParameters::$docId = DocList::$(.*)_VIEW;
```

On all matches. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing wrong is that the matched field delimited by `(` and `)` needs to be identified by `\1` in the replacement string:

```
GlobalParameters\:\:\$docId\ \=\ DocList\:\:\$\1_VIEW\;
```

It is also worth noting that, although your Geany implementation does not have this default, many programs which use regular expressions default to BRE (Basic Regular Expression) mode, which requires `\(` and `\)` to delimit the search subexpression, as in:

```
GlobalParameters\:\:\$docId\ \=\ DocList\:\:\$\(.*\)\;
```

Note: Geany as of v1.24 doesn't need the parentheses to be escaped, so you need just `(` and `)` to delimit matching fields.

Other, simpler search and replace strings occur to me, but without seeing the context of other strings in the file I am not sure which might be satisfactory. However, the following should be OK:-

Search:

```
\(GlobalParameters\:\:\$docId\ \=\ DocList\:\:\$.*\)\;
```

Replace:

```
\1_VIEW\;
```

Here the whole string apart from the trailing `;` is matched and `_VIEW` is appended.

Comment: But why do the parentheses have to be escaped? They're not part of the string that I need to match, but anyway I'm going to try this solution as soon as I get to my computer. Thank you.

Comment: The default for many programs which use regular expressions is BRE (Basic Regular Expression) mode, which requires escaping. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). When I tested your strings with `sed` I needed the back-slashes.

Comment: I didn't knew that, but maybe Geany doesn't use that mode by default.

Comment: I don't know Geany, so maybe you don't need the back-slashes, but you certainly need `\1` in the replacement stream to expand the marked subexpression. Try using this first, then add the back-slashes to the brackets if you need to.

Comment: Just tried it and works like a charm! Thank you! I really didn't know about grep's system to match fields, neat. Thank you again.

Comment: Did you need the back-slashes with the brackets? If you didn't I ought to modify my answer so that missing back-slashes are not classed as one of the things wrong.

Comment: Nope, I did not have to escape the brackets at all, maybe it's because how Geany calls grep (it uses it as it's internal string matching command).

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the "wrong" classification of the search string, but I've left the information in to help others with a related RE problem.

Answer (score 0):

To extend AFH's answer, I made a more complex example:

To-be-modified string:

```
abc: 123
```

Search:

```
(abc)\: (123)
```

Replace (1def will be appended to the first match expression and 456 to the second):

```
\1def \2456
```

Result:

```
abcdef 123456
```